# Two 'textbooks' tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think we should burnimate the latter.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[textbooks](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbooks) is already a synonym of [books](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books). It serves a useful purpose: if someone tries to add [textbooks](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbooks) to a question, the question will be tagged [books](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books). What's the benefit of eliminating the synonym?

Comment: I though that if the *textbooks* tag is already a synonym of the *books* tag, then it won't show as a separate tag when I search for it. No?

Comment: @Ooker that's not true, as you've found out. The point of synonyms is to help people who might search for a tag using the alternate name.

Comment: I know, but when I type *text(book)* instead of *book* in the tag field (which is the case of "who might search for a tag using the alternate name"), then it should only show the *books* tag, right? The *books* tag already have the line *also: textbooks* at the bottom.

Comment: @Ooker: That sounds like horrible UX. If I type *references* into a search field, I will be somewhat confused, if I see *citations* popping up and it usually takes me a while to notice the *also* note. This is particularly irritating, if my search yielded a lot of tags.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I prefer your explanation. If you make that into an answer, I will accept that. Otherwise I will happily accept this answer.

Comment: @Ooker: Accept this one. My comment explains why synonyms work the way they do, nothing more.